# indexOf() using ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, indexof

I've a class `A` which is as follows:

```
A{
     String name;
     ArrayList<Bike> firstArray;
     ArrayList<Cycle> secondArray;
     // it's constructors and related methods are down lines.
 }
```

and I have two instances of it named `a_Obj` and `b_obj`. I compare only the variable ,`name` inside object `a_Obj` with `b_Obj` using `indexOf`.

My question is how to call `indexOf` in this case and in other words how to tell the compiler that I just want to compare `name` of two objects regardless of ArrayLists declared inside the class `A`.

Answer (score 1):

you can override equals() in your class

Answer (score 0):

Given below is how `indexOf` has been implemented by default:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    ListIterator<E> it = listIterator();
    if (o==null) {
        while (it.hasNext())
            if (it.next()==null)
                return it.previousIndex();
    } else {
        while (it.hasNext())
            if (o.equals(it.next()))
                return it.previousIndex();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

By overriding the `equals` method in `A` to consider just the equality of `name`, you can make it happen.

Given below is the definition generated by Eclipse IDE:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    A other = (A) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

A shorter version for the same can be as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    A other = (A) obj;
    return Objects.equals(name, other.name);
}
```

Comment: `return name.equals(other.name);`

Comment: @WJS - I do not approve your suggested solution as it will throw `NullPointerException` when `name` is `null`.